# Stata type mismatch, and no report of line number where error happened

Tags: stata

I googled about "type mismatch", and it seems the errors mostly come from "replace"

Indeed I am doing some replacing but I can't see where that error comes from.

```
generate price=0.0
replace price=105.17 if year==2014

gen crisis=1 if year==2008 | year==2009
replace crisis=0 if year<2008 | year>2009

gen postcrisis=1 if year>2008
replace postcrisis=0 if year<=2008
```

Also, Stata isn't displaying at which line the error happened. This is very bad for debugging. How can I make it?

======================================

The error was coming from

```
generate realsales=sales/price
```

To see what is going wrong, I did the following.

```
. describe sales price

              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable
>  label
------------------------------------------------------
sales           str8    %9s                   
price           float   %9.0g
```

And destring didn't work.

```
. destring sales, replace
sales contains nonnumeric characters; no replace
```

Also, dataex didn't work.

```
. dataex
input statement exceeds linesize limit. Try specifying fewer variables
```

And still, when Stata stops with an error, it never tells me which line is causing the error. It simply shows me the following lines.

```
112. 
. }

(146 vars, 10748 obs)
type mismatch
r(109);

end of do-file

r(109);
```

This is very inconvenient for debugging. Is it really like this? Is there any way to make Stata display the error line?

Comment: Your `didn't work` statements miss the point in each case. `destring` is signalling that there are non-numeric characters and my `list` statement in a comment below, which you didn't try, gives a way to find out what they are. `dataex` is clearly telling you to try fewer variables and all you need show us are variables mentioned in your problem. I see no sign here that you have tried `set trace on`. Find out what the non-numeric characters are and use the options of `destring` to remove them.

Comment: Also, as you know that one statement is wrong, it is poor debugging strategy to repeat an entire `do`-file.

Comment: Following from your edits, `sales` contains nonnumeric characters. Presumably there are some values in your data that cannot be interpreted as numeric. Perhaps the data contains `$` or commas? Examine the contents of that variable and try `destring` with the `ignore` option. See `help destring` for syntax and usage.

Answer (score 1):

In turn as you tell us nothing about your variables, this isn't a reproducible example.

A type mismatch means that you trying to do something numeric to strings, or *vice versa*. In your examples, possibly `year` is a string variable somehow. If so,

```
destring year, replace
```

On debugging: Stata will stop with an error message as soon as it hits a problem. Otherwise, `help trace` to find out about program tracing.

Your example statements could all be condensed. In the last example, if crisis years are 2008 and 2009, you don't mean what you say.

```
generate price = cond(year == 2014, 105.17, 0) 

gen crisis = year==2008 | year==2009

gen postcrisis = year > 2009
```

Comment: Thank you. But it is not stopping at the error. It just stops without telling me anything about where it stopped.

Comment: I just commented out my code one line by one line. Found out "generate realsales=sales/price"  is causing the problem. "destring sales, replace" didn't help. price was already numeric. What could be the candidate cause ?

Comment: So, your problem turns out to arise from code you never showed us! Same problem: you are not showing reproducible examples. Please study http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Specifically, please edit your question to include a self-contained example. Hints: Use `dataex` (install with `ssc inst dataex`) to provide a data example. Show the results of `describe sales price` followed by `list sales if missing(real(sales))`.